How can I add anvil token from the test token provided to my metamask account
When I run the make anvil command in terminal it provide me a bunch of accounts with test accounts. I am not able to import tokens from test account to my metamask account

In order to add the test token deployed on Anvil chain. You need to perform the following steps:

Make sure the Anvil node is running locally.


Add Anvil network as a custom network manually to your MetaMask.


Make sure that the entered details exactly match with the configuration of the Anvil node which is running locally.


You can get the private key of the account(s) from the console of the running Anvil node.


Now, you've to import account in your MetaMask using the private key of the first account (i.e., the default account) of the Anvil chain.


After, the account is imported, it'll be shown like this:


Then, you've to import token in your MetaMask by clicking on Import tokens and entering the token contract address in the field.





Detail answer. The most important thing is the step #1 - ensure the Anvil node is running locally :D
